# Understanding Microsoft's Code Libraries

Tags: documentation

I'd like to learn what various code libraries, which I think are all Microsoft's, do. Example libraries include atls.lib, atlsd.lib, libcmtd.lib, libcpmtd.lib. Would you point me to a good online reference or other way to learn about these libraries?

Clarification: I'm hoping to find an index of sorts for learning about Microsoft libraries in general. Sadly, when I search the web for something like "libcmtd", I just get posts on forums from people having problems with their code. Since Google doesn't report anything promising looking within the first few pages, there might not be anything, but it's worth asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATLS.LIB is the static version of ATL.  (ATLSD.LIB is the debug version of that.)  ATL documentation starts here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9adwcde.aspx

LIBCMTD.LIB and LIBCPMTD.LIB are the debug versions of the C and C++ runtime libraries.  They're pretty standard implementations, so any C and C++ library reference will do.  Microsoft has them documented on MSDN.

By "debug versions", I mean that these versions of the libraries have extra checking in them to help uncover bugs at run-time.  These are generally appropriate for your debug builds.  When building your release build, you probably want the regular versions which drop the final 'd' from the file names.

Comment: ... and the 'mt' suffix means that it's safe to call this library from multi-threaded code (e.g. so that it's safe for multiple threads to call 'malloc' or 'operator new').

Comment: Also, at least for mscrtdXX, the debug version is not included in the VSXXX redistributable package, so you cannot distribute a program compiled against the debug C runtime.  I'm not sure if it's a legal reason or just out of convention.

Answer (score 0):

in addition msvcrt.lib and msvcrtd.lib are c runtime lib if you use MFs Microsoft foundation classes.

And there are unicode versions of all these libraries as well.

See afx.h and look for a set of #ifdef's that select which libraries to
"use" by default, puts a pragma lib comment in the output.

In many cases, it is literally impossible to link because of this, if you get libraries (shared or not) from different sources, or the same source from different versions.

Basically, MS painted themselves into a corner by doing lots of compile time decisions that really can't be made at compile time, like deciding what your library will ever link with, or deciding all programs only speak unicode or non unicode.

You cant link modules compiled for debug with modules that are not compiled for debug.
Why would you want to? Because you got a library from somewhere to link with. If that libary does anything with windows, it forces you to use all non-debug compiles to use it, if it s a no-debug library. (The exception is if the library does not depend on the c runtime libary, ATL or MFC. Ironic that C / C++ work better with libraries NOT written in C++, and ironic that Windows works better with libraries that don't use, well, a Window (mfc or atl).)

Notice there are no longer software libraries to buy to help do this or that in Windows?
MS made it impossible. You would have to make 32, yes 32 versions to cover all the MFC/ATL/Cruntime possibilities there are, and even then it would not work, because 
many of the MS libraries just wont link or will link and wont work together in 
combinations that appear to link ok.